# How can I parse nested GenericRecord containing Union, Map, Array etc.?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am having the genericRecord as well as the schema. I want to parse all the fields and append some text only to those values whose type is String.

Assume that schema is like this:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"MyRecord",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"a",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "int",
            {
               "type":"map",
               "values":"string"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I don't want to write nested if else statements that I have already done and recursively called them. Is there any other efficient way ?

Comment: Are you using spark or is it for web application?

Comment: I am using Java. Data is coming from a Kafka cluster and I am trying to encode the string values to base64 and put it in the same genericRecord and send to other applications.

Comment: Is it not possible to use functional programming to extract? Probably you should also give example of what you want in a list or map because this is little bit unclear.

Comment: Assume that this is the sample record ::

{
   "active":true,
   "Identifier":"ABC:A:2019-01-01",
   "commentText":null,
   "coverageType":{
      "code":"A",
      "description":null
   }
} 
What I want is i want to go through each field and do the transformation only if the type of that field is String. Now if I just start a loop on top of this then for coverageType 
{
      "code":"A",
      "description":null
   }
This will print but what I want is, as in this case it is a UNION in schema. So I want to go inside it and do the transformation.

Comment: but I don't  want to have nested if else statements specifying the types that can come. As that is not the best approach. So any suggestions, if there is any library or some function available or any other input.